# jQuery clearinterval doesn't work / doesn't clear the interval across all events

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, setinterval, clearinterval

I have an autorefresh function that gets called if a checkbox is checked and a button is clicked. It autorefreshes a table from a php file with certain variables bound to that button. When another button (with different variables bound to it) is clicked, the autorefresh must stop, i.e. the interval must be cleared.
This however I cannot get to work, the intervals just add up - the old one isn't cleared - although I try to call my clearinterval function at about every possible place in my code.

This is how my file is made up:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});

var refreshId = null;

function stopinterval() {
    clearInterval(refreshId);
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button1").click(function(infralivefun) {
        event.preventDefault(infralivefun);

        var category_id = {};
        category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
        category_id['datumend'] = $("#datumend").datepicker().val();

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "infratestomc.php?id=" + Math.random(),
            dataType: "html",      
            data: category_id,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resulttabelle").show().html(response);
            }
        });

        if ($('#autorefcheck').is(':checked')) {
            refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                var category_id = {};
                category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
                category_id['datumend'] = $("#datumend").datepicker().val();

                $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "infratestomc.php?id=" + Math.random(), 
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: category_id,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#resulttabelle").show().html(response);
                    }
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
        //trying to call the stopinterval inside the button.Click event below
        $('#button2').click(function() {
            stopinterval();
        });

        $('#button3').click(function() {
            stopinterval();
        });

        $('#autorefcheck').click(function() {
            stopinterval();
        });

    }); //end of on.click(button)


    //here I'm trying to call clearinterval outside of the button.click
    $('#button2').click(function() {
          stopinterval();
    });

    $('#button3').click(function() {
         stopinterval();
    });

    $('#autorefcheck').click(function() {
         stopinterval();
    });

}); //end of document.ready
```

Imagine that the button2 and button3 have similar make-ups just with other variables passed to the php. I would be extremely glad if someone could point me in the right direction as to how I can just clear that interval throughly when I click on something else!

Comment: I'm not sure about why it's not working, but have you considered what happens if the user clicks twice on button 1? You will lose the reference to the previous interval and never get that back.

Comment: Actually, that could be one reason for your problem. Do you happen to call the same setInterval for the other buttons without clearing it first?

Comment: @Aioros hm I'm not quite sure I understand, I kind of _do_ want to lose all reference to previous intervals if something is clicked!
Yes I do call the same setInterval for the other buttons, I thought it gets cleared when i click another button (see the last part of the code)

Comment: Ok, but you have to call your `stopInterval()` before the `setInterval()`, otherwise `refreshId` will change and you will have no way to clear the interval you previously set. I'm not sure this is your situation, but it could definitely happen by clicking twice on button 1.

Comment: @Aioros I'm pretty sure I'm missing out on something very basic. Can you please lead me in the right direction how I correctly clear the interval before I call it again?

Comment: Well, putting a `stopInterval();` before any `refreshId = setInterval();` could be enough. I'll post an answer, might be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you click the button multiple times you will have multiple intervals running since you never check to see if it is running.

```
if ($('#autorefcheck').is(':checked')) {
    stopinterval(); //cancel it if it is already set
    refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        ...
```

Also adding click events inside other click events is a bad idea. Because on every click, you are adding multiple click handlers to those other elements.

Answer (score 1):

A little **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/e40sf8fv/)** for help!

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false}); //Are you sure of it?

$(function(){
    var refreshId='';
    function stopinterval() {
        clearInterval(refreshId);
        return false;
    }
    $("#button1").on('click',function(infralivefun) {
        event.preventDefault(infralivefun);

        var category_id = {};
        category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
        category_id['datumend'] = $("#datumend").datepicker().val();

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "infratestomc.php?id=" + Math.random(),
            dataType: "html",      
            data: category_id,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resulttabelle").show().html(response);
            }
        });

        if ($('#autorefcheck').is(':checked')) {
                refreshId = setInterval(function(){
                    var category_id = {};
                    category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
                    category_id['datumend'] = $("#datumend").datepicker().val();
                },5000);

                $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "infratestomc.php?id=" + Math.random(), 
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: category_id,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#resulttabelle").show().html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $('#button2, #button3, #autorefcheck').on('click',stopinterval);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the source of your problems, but it's definitely a possible problem: you have one single global variable holding the interval IDs.
Let's say the user clicks on button 1; you store the `refreshID` in order to clear it later. Then the user clicks on button 1 again (or another button, actually), and `refreshId` gets another (different) value. So you will never be able to clear the first one.

The easiest way to avoid this is to try to clear the interval before every `setInterval()` call:

```
stopinterval();
refreshId = setInterval(...)
```

In general, it might be a good idea to store each new interval in a different variable, maybe inside a globally accessible object, so that you can manage the IDs as you prefer. Something like:

```
myIntervals.push({"button1": setInterval(...)});
```